# How to reword this: repeated back on him?

Tags: style

I don't know how to reword this:

> Along the way, we see how the faults
>   Jacob made earlier in life are
>   repeated back on him.

I know

> repeated back on him

doesn't sound correct, but I don't know what to replace it with.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all, it's "the mistakes" he made — one doesn't make faults

- are revisited upon him
- return upon him
- come back to bite him in the [tuchus]
- come back to haunt him
- come home to roost
- beat a path back to his door [a play
  on "if you build a better mousetrap,
  the world will beat a path to your
  door"]

Answer (score 1):

How about "...we see how Jacob repeats the mistakes he made earlier in life?"

Answer (score 0):

we see how the faults Jacob made earlier in his life begin to bleed back into his existence, recurring endlessly like an abyss in trepidation, an inflatable nightmare; draining through fading, whispered telephone conversations in the winter drear.

Comment: Can we say purple prose?

Comment: put down the magnetic poetry set and step away from the refrigerator, slowly!

Comment: sorry guys xxxx